How to get all four corner coordinates in MAP BOX using jetpack compose
I want to get all corner(topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight) coordinates (Lat, Lng) here is the code
      MapboxMap(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        mapInitOptionsFactory = { context ->
            MapInitOptions(
                context = context,
                styleUri = Style.STANDARD,
            )
        },
        mapViewportState = mapViewportState,
        compassSettings = compassSettings,
        scaleBarSettings = scaleBarSetting,
        gesturesSettings = mapBoxUiSettings,
        attributionSettings = AttributionSettings {
            enabled = false
        },
    ) {
        MapEffect(key1 = Unit) { mapView ->
            mapView.mapboxMap.subscribeMapIdle(mapIdleCallback = {
                Log.d("Tag", "Idle ${mapView.mapboxMap.cameraState.center}")
            })
        }
    } // : MapboxMap

When mapbox is idle mapIdleCallback is triggered now what are the methods I need to call to get the four coordinates. Any help would be appreciated.

Update; I was able to get coordinates after a little more code research
MapboxMap(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        mapInitOptionsFactory = { context ->
            MapInitOptions(
                context = context,
                styleUri = Style.STANDARD,
            )
        },
        mapViewportState = mapViewportState,
        compassSettings = compassSettings,
        scaleBarSettings = scaleBarSetting,
        gesturesSettings = mapBoxUiSettings,
        attributionSettings = AttributionSettings {
            enabled = false
        },
    ) {
        MapEffect(key1 = Unit) { mapView ->
            mapView.mapboxMap.subscribeMapIdle(mapIdleCallback = {
                val coordinateBounds =
                    mapView.mapboxMap.coordinateBoundsForCamera(mapView.mapboxMap.cameraState.toCameraOptions())
                // Extract individual corner coordinates
                val southwest = coordinateBounds.southwest
                val northeast = coordinateBounds.northeast
                // Calculate other corner coordinates
                val northwest = Point.fromLngLat(southwest.longitude(), northeast.latitude())
                val southeast = Point.fromLngLat(northeast.longitude(), southwest.latitude())
                list = listOf(
                    southwest,
                    northwest,
                    northeast,
                    southeast,
                    southwest
                )
            })
        }
    } // : MapboxMap

The method I was looking for is mapView.mapboxMap.cameraState.toCameraOptions() which provided me with northEast and southWest coordinates I was then able to get other two coordinates by using basic map coordination techniques.
